# What does this condition do (BufferredReader and InputStreamReader)?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, inputstreamreader

I'm currently reading a code and i found a method starting like this :

```
BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));  

String userInput;

while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {

  }
```

Can someone explain me the condition while ? That a = b != c seems weird to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your eyes are glancing over a pair of parentheses:

```
while ( (userInput = stdIn.readLine() ) != null) {

}
```

I've attempted to make it more clear above.

The variable `userInput` is being assigned `stdIn.readLine()`. And while `userInput` isn't null following that assignment, the loop continues.

It's just a one-liner for handling the `userInput` update, as well as checking for `null`

Answer (score 1):

The assignment in brackets `(userInput = stdIn.readLine())` does two things at once: it assigns the line to userInput variable **and** evaluates itself to this value. But if nothing was read, the `readLine()` returns `null`, and whole expression evaluates to `null`.

So while there are lines in the user input, the condition `(userInput = stdIn.readLine() ) != null` holds, and the `while` loop continues. When there are no more lines in the user input, the condition is false, and the `while` loop stops.

Answer (score 1):

`=` is an assignment operator, not a comparison operator.

`(a = b) != c` assigns `b`'s value to `a`, and then compares it to `c`.

In the case of

```
while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) { ... }
```

`stdIn.readLine()` is getting a value, which is then stored as `userInput`, and that value is checked to make sure it isn't `null` in order for the while loop to progress. This results in the loop reading each line of the file until it runs out of lines to read.

Answer (score 1):

It is something like:

```html
int a = 0;
int b = 0;

while ((a = b++) != 10) {

    System.out.println(a);

};
```

Here we are assigning a with increment of `b`, and checking whether its value is 10 or not.

Same way, `userInput = stdIn.readLine()` means we are reading a line, assign it to `userInput` variable and checking until it reads `null`.